# SQL Date Range - Select all if no start point supplied?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having hard time figuring out how I can select records if my (Between From AND To) is missing From.

Eg. On the form I have date range, and if user enters only TO and leaves FROM blank how can I select ALL records up to that point.

My issue occures here,

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN from AND to;

This is my query and I would like to use this same query and just modify my variables so that I don't have to have multiple SELECTS depending on what data was entered.

Thanks

Comment: Set [from] to a real out of range value (01-01-1900) to keep the where clause sargable and allow index use (if there is one)

Comment: Alex I used this, i put in if before query and done it like that.. works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you arrange your application to have two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN $from AND $to
```

and:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date <= $to
```

Then choose the query based on whether or not `$from` is suppled.

Why?  Both queries can take advantage of an index on `date`.  In general, MySQL does a poor job of recognizing index usage with an `or` condition.

Alternatively, you can use AlexK's suggest and set `$from` to some ridiculously old date and use the query in the OP.

Comment: I have actually used 1 query but i did if statement before and set a date to 1900 if FROM is empty.. works good thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ($from = '' AND date <= $to) OR 
      (date BETWEEN $from AND $to);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this with Giorgos' selection above, or using a union:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN $from AND $to
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE date <= $to AND $from IS NULL
```

Personally I think Giorgos' solution is a bit cleaner, but there are times you'll want a UNION so I'm including for completeness sake.